# How to jump to the next row in detailview

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, row, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i have a TableView which loads a detailview in didSelectRow. I have no problems with the data's.
I am using coreData and to populate the TableView i am using a NSFetchedResultsController.

Now, i want to make a next and previous function in the detailView **to jump to the next or previous Table(row) Element**. Next Previous like in the Mail-App.
I know that i have to use a button with IBAction.

**But how can i make this function?**

thanks,
brush51

**Edit 1:**
I have it done so:

```
- (IBAction) previousCard:(id) sender {  
    NSLog(@"previousBtn");

DashboardViewController *parent = (DashboardViewController *)self.parentViewController;

NSIndexPath *actualIndexPath = selectedRow2;
NSIndexPath * newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath  indexPathForRow:actualIndexPath.row-1 inSection:actualIndexPath.section];
NSLog(@"newIndexPath: %@", newIndexPath);
[parent.tableViews selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle]; //HERE I GET SIGABRT

}
```

But i get an error:

```
-[UIViewController tableViews]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd758ae0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableViews]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd758ae0'
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With your UITableView, you can get the selected row by:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow
```

And set the selection by incrementing the indexPath.row:

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

then you action could be:

```
-(IBAction)nextCell:(id)sender {
  NSIndexPath * actualIndexPath = myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
  NSIndexPath * newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath  indexPathForRow:actualIndexPath.row+1 inSection:actualIndexPath.section];
  [myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And how can i set my tableView here in the detailview? or am i missing a part here?

Comment: You can add a reference in your detail view controller to the parent controller, assign the parent controller on didSelectRowAtIndexPath when you push your detail controller

Comment: And how to do that? Can you explain it please? Iam sorry for my low experience in ios.

Comment: ok, the reference is done with: (MyParentViewController *)self.parentViewController. i can now use the table from the parentView, but i get an error in **indexPathForSelectedRow**: -[UIViewController tblViewC]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4eaa7b0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tblViewC]: unrecognized...What i have exactly to do didSelectRowAtIndexPath? How to assign the partentController there? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

for that you can manage with your DataSource array.

when you load your detail view at that time you pass your index of array(indexPath.row). by that index you fetch data in detail view. and using increment and decrement in that index you get data for next and previous cell.

**Steps**

1) setup your tableView.

2) when redirect to DetailView at that time set one int variable for store current indexPath.row . so define one int in detail View.

3) using next and previous button manage indexpath.row which is in int variable. 
and represent appropriate data from Source array.

Comment: ok, i have passed the indexPath to the detailview. and how can i fetch the data in my detailview with the indexpath?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`(UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

To get the cell you want (next or previous).

And then set the returned cell "Selected" property to YES.

`cell.selected = YES`