# How to jump to next row in detailView?

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, master-detail

How can I **jump to the next row in DetailViewController**? Like in the Mail app

I passed the indexPath from the MasterViewController to DetailViewController, then I created a new indexPath for the next row:

```
NSIndexPath * newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath  indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
```

I also found this solution
[How to jump to the next row in detailview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874524/how-to-jump-to-the-next-row-in-detailview)
,but this only describes, how to jump from the MasterViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:)

The above method can be called on detail view's table view to make it scroll to the new row

If you want to just select the next row.. you can explicitly call the delegate method of table view `didSelectRow` with your index path.